# Display google chart using python and refresh data every 10 seconds

Tags: python

I need to display google chart using python and random 2 integer every 10 seconds, replace the integer into the chart then display on the browser.

Here is my code, I am new to python and have no idea what is wrong with my code

```
import random
import time

while True:

     f = open('message.html', 'w')

     message1 = '<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">'

     message2 = "google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);function drawChart() {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],"

     message3 = "['Work', "

     message4 = "],           ['Sleep',"

     message5 = "]]);var options = {title: 'My Daily Activities'};var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));chart.draw(data, options);}</script></head><body>"

     message6 = '<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div></body></html>'

     a = random.randint(0, 101)

     b = random.randint(0, 101)

     message = message1 + message2 + message3 + str(a) + message4 + str(b) + message5 + message6

     f.write(message)

     time.sleep(10)

     f.close()
```

I tried to print a and b in the terminal, it random perfectly but the chart didn't display on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write as there and reload html to view result after 10s:

```
 f.write(message)
 f.close()
 time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, I feel terrible with my poor logic.